# How to compress files as much as possible in JS Uglify2?

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

I am new to js uglify 2 https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2 and I am trying to figure out how to compress a bunch of js files as much as possible, but not have anything break. So far I have this:

```
var result = uglifyJS.minify([ 
    "A.js", "B.js"
], {
    mangle :true,
    compress: {
        sequences: true,
        properties: true,
        dead_code: true,
        drop_debugger: true,
        conditionals :true,
        evaluate :true,
        booleans :true,
        loops:true,
        unused:true,
        hoist_funs: true,
        if_return:true,
        join_vars:true,
        cascade :true,
        collapse_vars :true,
        global_defs: {
            DEBUG: false
        }
    }
});
```

Does anyone know if this is right, and what else I can change/add?

Also for `properties` option, it apparently changes things like `a["b"]` into `a.b`, but what if I had `a[" s"]` would it change it into `a. s`?  Because that would break it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get better compression still add these additional compress options:

```
    pure_getters: true,
    unsafe_comps: true,
    screw_ie8: true,
```

and this option is generally safe for most code:

```
    unsafe: true,
```

Uglify won't transform `a[" s"]` into `a. s`.